# non overlaping choice lists in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, validation, multiple-choice

Using Symfony 2.2.4.

I have a form with two choice lists(multiple,non expanded) showing the same elements(entities of a class). I need to throw an error(onsubmit) when the user selects the same element from both choice lists. Is there a way to validate this selection that does not need to traverse both lists checking each element, you know, like an automatic/built in validation.

I need to catch the error and bind it to one of the choice lists in a way that allows me to show it as any other error, meaning through form_errors(form).

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to add a listener in the buildForm of the AbstractType class, here an example

```
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $coll1 = $form['field1']->getData();
            $coll2 = $form['field2']->getData();
            $ids1 = $coll1->map(function($entity) { return $entity->getId(); })->toArray();
            $ids2 = $coll1->map(function($entity) { return $entity->getId(); })->toArray();
            $intersect = array_intersect($ids1, $ids2);
            if (!empty($intersect)) {
                $form['field1']->addError(
                    new FormError('here the error')
                );
            }
        }
    );
```

Note that I have not tested the intersection of the collections but I hope the meaning is clear

Another (a bit hardest) way is to create a custom validation constraint

[here the cookbook from symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: I ended up validating it in the controller, regarding your answer I didn't actually try it but I have a doubt about it: does it throw the error _when both arrays are equal element-by-element_ or _when at least one element is in both arrays_? 
because I need the latter

Comment: well, looks like you changed the answer as I was writing, in the end I used the array_intersect function too, only in the controller, since I have never worked with the listeners, newbie me, 
and so far it's worked but just to be sure, would it be a problem to intersect the entities instead of the ids?, could it go wrong for some reason in the future?

Comment: probably directly intersecting the entity works equally, but i'm not sure, i trust more with ids:)